# How easy is finding related vanity addresses?

Tags: vanity-address, vanitygen

Is it easy to find out related vanity address '**1googlex**' if we already know '**1google**' vanity address pair, than through usual vanitygen iteration process? if yes, can this be extended further, like, '**1googlexx**', without exponentially increasing difficulty?

Comment: From answers I understand that it is also equally difficult for vanitygen tool to hit same pair twice (with no random number seed). right?

Comment: I will add this as a separate question, by referring this question and answer page, for better visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a vanity address is a random process. Even if we find an address with N letters we are interested in, it does not change anything about finding an address of N+1 letters.

Finding an additional letter in a vanity address pattern requires on average performing 58 times as many calculations as it took to find the original length.

Answer (score 4):

Zero. They are completely unrelated.

And if you think about that, it is quite obvious... otherwise it would be very easy to steal known addresses: you would just have to find a similar one.