# How to make a vanity throwaway address? Similar to 1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSendf59kuE

Tags: address, vanity-address, base58

I want to write data to the Blockchain, and write to specific addresses.

I want to send small amounts of Bitcoin to addresses like this:

`1MikesReallyCoolApp<game_id_here>59kuE`

How can I do this while still maintaining a valid address to send BTC to?

Is there someone who can breakdown the parts of a Bitcoin address that can be altered? I know each address needs a "1" in the beginning, but not sure about the other rules.

Comment: related: [How do I check the checksum of a Bitcoin address?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/32363/5406), [How easy is finding related vanity addresses?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/7649/5406)

Comment: Note that the blockchain is not meant to write data to, especially not in this way. Have a look at OP_RETURN please.

Comment: Do you want to make burn addresses or vanity addresses? I thought the latter, but the answerer appears to think the former.

Answer (score 3):

Simple website to create burn address http://gobittest.appspot.com/ProofOfBurn
If you want a script try this https://gist.github.com/CoinWhisperer/6d673f1f3d13da1611cd